# How to get <b> tag without class using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I am working on getting information about a product listed [here](https://www.tokopedia.com/naturashop27/bio-oil-original-penghilang-bekas-luka-strecth-mark-isi-125ml?whid=0). I am using Selenium and Google Colab . I am having a problem accessing the text on the b tag. For other attributes such as name, seller, price, etc. can be **scraped** without problems.

This is the snippet of the HTML.

```html
<div class="css-1le9c0d pad-bottom">
    <img src="https://assets.tokopedia.net/assets-tokopedia-lite/v2/zeus/kratos/3ac8f50c.svg" alt="">
    <div>Dikirim dari 
      <b>Kota Depok</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my driver settings.

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
webdriver_path = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                                                                     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                                                                     'Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'})
```

This is the code that I have tried.

```py
sample_link = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/naturashop27/bio-oil-original-penghilang-bekas-luka-strecth-mark-isi-125ml?whid=0'
driver.get(sample_link)
time.sleep(1.5)

try:
    product = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')[0].text
except:
    product = np.nan

try:
    shop_url = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='css-1n8curp']"))).get_attribute("href")
except:
    shop_url = np.nan

# ....

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b")))
    loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b").text
except:
    loc = np.nan
```

This is the output from the code above. As you can see, the text on the b tag is nan instead of Kota Depok.

```
Bio Oil Original Penghilang Bekas Luka & Strecth Mark isi 125ml
https://www.tokopedia.com/naturashop27
nan
```

Please see the solution below. The issues are the following:

- element is not loaded fully before scraping the element.
- Using driver.set_window_size(1124,850) works in Colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wanna try this :

Element is not in Selenium view port, you need to scroll a bit to get the job done.

```
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'pad-bottom')]"))).text)
except:
    loc = np.nan
```

**O/P :**

```
Dikirim dari Kota Depok

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have used this xpath : `//div[contains(@class, 'pad-bottom')]` that will print `Dikirim dari Kota Depok`

if you use `//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b` you will get `Kota Depok`

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/naturashop27/bio-oil-original-penghilang-bekas-luka-strecth-mark-isi-125ml?whid=0")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h1"))).text)
except:
    product = np.nan

try:
    shop_url = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-testid='llbPDPFooterShopName']"))).get_attribute("href")
    print(shop_url)
except:
    shop_url = np.nan

try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'pad-bottom')]"))).text)
except:
    loc = np.nan
```

**This gives me  :**

```
Bio Oil Original Penghilang Bekas Luka & Strecth Mark isi 125ml
https://www.tokopedia.com/naturashop27
Dikirim dari Kota Depok

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you have the full code to run this? I think I'm having a problem with the driver.

Comment: @ElvanSelvano : Do you have any more concerns ? what is the driver issue  ?

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, in Colab it is empty.

Comment: Update: driver.set_window_size(1124,850) works in colab. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in your selector, try using

`//div[@class='css-1le9c0d pad-bottom']/div/b`

instead of

`/div[@class='css-1le9c0d pad-bottom']/div/b`

You missed a slash

Comment: Oops, sorry that was a mistake. I have updated the original code.

Comment: Are you sure the element is in visibility? if not can you scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `css-1le9c0d` class name. The `pad-bottom` class name is unique enough.
Also, you do not need to use `find_elements_by_xpath`, just use `find_element_by_xpath`.

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b").text
```

**UPD**
Try using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b")))
```

instead of

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b")))
```

**UPD2**
Or maybe try this:

```
loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b").get_attribute("textContent")
```

Or this:

```
loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Instead of

```
loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pad-bottom')]//b").text
```

Comment: Do you run in headless mode? Do you maximize the screen size?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the original code with my driver settings.

Comment: Try using visibility instead of presence

Comment: Still get nan, other attributes work fine though.

Comment: It is strange... Please try my new suggestion. Hope it will work